# Screen Calibration in WinCE

Tags: c#, c++, windows-ce

I know I can set the calibration with the function `TouchCalibrate`.  I don't want to use the windows function I want to set the calibration via the registry.  This works fine except I don't know what message to send to the OS to let it know the data has been update.  Does anyone know what message I need to send?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the CE private source installed on this machine to verify, but I believe you need to broadcast a `WM_SETTINGSCHANGE` message.